# Training R Keras Model using cloudml fails

Tags: r, keras, google-cloud-ml

I'm just getting started with deep learning with R and am trying to figure out how to train a keras model on a Google Cloud GPU using the cloudml package.

I've been playing with the Nietzsche text generation example from here -
https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/lstm_text_generation.html - and it runs fine on my local machine but, unfortunately, doesn't execute properly when I try to run it using the cloudml package.

I saved the example code as "nietzsche_eg.R" and then ran the following code -

```
library (cloudml)

options (gcloud.binary.path="C:/Users/taman/AppData/Local/Google/CloudSDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud")
options (gsutil.binary.path="C:/Users/taman/AppData/Local/Google/CloudSDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil")

cloudml_train ("nietzsche_eg.R", master_type = "standard_p100")
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error -

```
Error: ValueError: Layer lstm_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>. Full input: [<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f64b3b75610>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors. Detailed traceback: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 500, in __call__ return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__ self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 285, in assert_input_compatibility str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
```

Any help or insight into what's going wrong is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I know you just copied-and-pasted the example, but does it run locally? The error is indicative of a malformed model -- it seems that the Model object is being passed as input to the LSTM layer (rather than the actual input). I'm not very familiar enough with the R syntax to know how it should be, but `model %>% layer_lstm` seems to match the tutorials I've seen.

Comment: It does run locally. So I'm thinking something is not configured correctly on my cloud project.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't think I'm going to be able to help here. The error message makes it sound as if `model %>% fit(model, ...)` is being called. The only thing I can think to do is contact the authors of the R package and/or try different runtime versions.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the input text file from Google cloud storage and not via http, right? The cloudmle workers can not reach out outside the Google data center.

Comment: I ran the part to read and tokenize text and that part ran fine. I printed part of the text to check and its there. The rest of the code does run locally so I'm not sure what's going wrong on the cloud.

Comment: How did you print the text while sending the training application to the ML engine? Trying to get more information about what's going on within the ML engine training process and not just receiving the response of the execution.